# How do I prevent he COUNT(XXXX) from displaying in the result set in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Query and result set below I don't want COUNT(PAY_ID) to display but need it for the calc.

```
SELECT
    INVOICE_NUM, COUNT(PAY_ID)
FROM TRANSACTION 
JOIN INVOICE USING (INVOICE_NUM)
JOIN PAYMENT USING (PAY_ID)
GROUP BY INVOICE_NUM
HAVING COUNT(PAY_ID) > 1
ORDER BY INVOICE_NUM
LIMIT 15;
```

Results

```
'2','2'
'4','2'
'7','4'
'8','2'
'10','3'
'12','2'
'15','3'
'16','3'
'19','2'
'23','2'
'30','2'
'31','2'
'40','2'
'50','2'
```

![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hZbP.png)

Comment: Just dont select the `COUNT(PAY_ID)`..

Comment: Adding images of result sets is discouraged.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Anyway code questions require a [mre] & that includes cut & paste & runnable code including example data as code.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't select it:

```
SELECT INVOICE_NUM
FROM TRANSACTION t
JOIN INVOICE i USING (INVOICE_NUM) 
JOIN PAYMENT p USING (PAY_ID)
GROUP BY INVOICE_NUM
HAVING COUNT(PAY_ID) > 1
ORDER BY INVOICE_NUM
LIMIT 15;
```